# Which robotium program should i write to launch application if i have only .apk file?

Tags: robotium

I wanted to know what code should i write in my program just to launch an application of which only .apk file is with me?

1. I have .apk file
2. I have robotium.jar file
3. I have used information provided on site "https://github.com/jayway/robotium-samples/blob/master/test-without-source/robotium-any-apk-howto.txt"

I am stuck at the step for resigning the .apk file mentioned at line no:29 under above mentioned link. I have used code provided in above mentioned link. But when i used that code i got errors such as "cannot instantiate the type solo" (Line 70) and "Undefined methods" for (Line 73, 77, 81). I have changed target package id and launcher class name as per .apk file which i have.

Comment: have you tried anything? please provide some attempts you did and their results.

Comment: cool! Edit your comment above because the url you provide has an extra `"` at the end, and add this information in your question.

Comment: Will i get help for this??